# Is there a way to directly convert dom to rich text format

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quill, rich-text-editor

The customer has a requirement to convert the current form report content into an editable form.

I tried to put the whole innerHTML of the entire dom into quill, but the css and images will be lost. I also tried contenteditale = true, it seems that the whole content can be edited, but it is obviously not as easy to use as a rich text editor. Is there any way to convert most of the content, styles, and pictures in the dom into rich text? Or is there another good way to make the content editable

Comment: can you provide [mcve] of what you have tried

Comment: maybe like <form contenteditable="true" id="editor" /> or  <vue-quill-editor v-model="innerHTML" /> and so on

Comment: You mean you have a dom tree and you want to move them to a text editor right?

Comment: yes, just like you said, like html2pdf converts dom to pdf, I want to convert dom to rich text format